# Getting absolute values of double array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, double, absolute

I have a double array of the type:

```
    let a = [-1.0, 2.0, 3.4, -4.12, -0.05, 5.5]
```

Is there an easy way to get its absolute values:

```
    let aAbs = [1.0, 2.0, 3.4, 4.12, 0.05, 5.5]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even simpler, you can pass the `abs` function directly:

```
let absolutes = inputs.map(abs)
```

Comment: I was about to comment it on rmaddy's answer. I prefer this syntax

Answer (score 2):

A simple `map` will do it:

```
let a = [-1.0, 2.0, 3.4, -4.12, -0.05, 5.5]
let aAbs = a.map { abs($0) }
```

Comment: Thanks Maddy -- was looking for something like this !